# pyspark rdd.map function takes 3 minutes to run on 32 rows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a csv file which I converted to a pyspark dataframe and I filtered the unique brands of cars using the following command:

```
df.select('make').distinct().collect()
```

This took around a second to execute and returns 32 rows of unique car brands from the column 'make'. But when I try to get the results as a list using the following command:

```
make_df.select('make').distinct().rdd.map(lambda x: x).collect()
```

it takes around 3 minutes to execute. I'm a newbie so I'm not sure what is going on behind the scenes to be able to articulate an appropriate question. Help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance of RDD operations in PySpark is really bad, since the driver doesn't know what your lambda is doing and therefore doesn't have the possibility of optimising the execution graph.

When using the DataFrame API, Spark knows exactly what you want to do and therefore can optimise the execution.

This [video](https://youtu.be/Ofk7G3GD9jk?t=1489) is pretty helpful on that topic.

Comment: Great I'll look into it, thanks! Is there a dataframe version of what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: `list(df.select('make').toPandas()['make'])`

Comment: If this helped you, an upvote would be appreciated!